# Ports required for NFS share to be used by RHEL / CentOS

Tags: centos, nfs, windows-server-2012-r2, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have a WS2K12 R2 server that is serving a NFS accessed by CentOS 7 / RHEL 7 if I turn my Firewall off it works with it on it doesn't.

Question Is: What are the ports required for the NFS Share (TCP / UDP) (In / Out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These services are defined within the /etc/services file.  I believe the port you're looking for is 2049 tcp and udp.
Good luck.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, windows has the services file as well within the C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc folder. Glad to hear the ports were right ;)

Comment: Well I also had 111, 1110, 4045 from my research but I had not come across the 2049.